# Show how many time date repeats in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a table which contains dates. I'd like to count those dates and show them how many times they've been repeated... For example:

```
startDate         count(*)
07-01-2016        17
09-02-2016        14
11-05-2016        77
```

And so on... the startDate column is DATETIME datatype.. (for example 07-01-2016 07:15, 07-01-2016 21:44) - and this should be calculated as two times because it is on the same date.

I was trying to convert datatype to date and then to group them, but it is not working. It shows only one date.

```
SELECT  CAST(startDate as DATE), COUNT(*)
FROM        myTable
GROUP BY    startDate
HAVING      COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by `CAST(startDate as DATE)` instead

```
SELECT  CAST(startDate as DATE), COUNT(*)
FROM        myTable
GROUP BY    CAST(startDate as DATE)
HAVING      COUNT(*) > 1;
```

or using DATE function

```
SELECT  DATE(startDate), COUNT(*)
FROM        myTable
GROUP BY    DATE(startDate)
HAVING      COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, `DATE()` is the easiest way.  You also need to include this in both the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT DATE(startDate) as StartDate, COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY DATE(startDate)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Using `CAST()` will also work.  However, I only use that when needed -- it doesn't work in Oracle, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
    date_format(startDate, "%Y-%m-%d")
    , COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM        myTable
GROUP BY    date_format(startDate, "%Y-%m-%d")
HAVING      cnt > 1;
```